# crypt-luks can it be removed to create more space

Tags: 16.04, encryption

[image]

It seems like crypt-luks is not being used but is taking up a considerable amount of space. Can I remove it?

Comment: Is this how you set up your system?

Comment: Yes @George but perhaps unintentionally.

Comment: Removing it is possible but it means re-install or reformat and all data will be lost. So backup, and I would suggest a re-install

Comment: Please edit your question and elaborate on "crypt-luk is not been used".  Where do you think your home folder is? Where are Ubuntu system files? I think they are all inside crypt-luk. Delete it and they will be gone for ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do not try to remove it. It *is* in use!

Assuming your image is showing your main drive where your normal system partitions are installed, that LUKS partition *is* being used! Gparted is unable to properly display LUKS partitions. If you want to see just how your LUKS partition is being used, try running `lsblk` in a terminal. You should see output that looks something like this:
[image: 01.png]

The part that I have highlighted in yellow reflects my LUKS partition on my machine. Of course yours should be listed under mmcblk0p3.

If you're looking to see how much space is in use on the partitions contained in the LUKS partition, try running `df -h`.

---

**Unsolicited advice**
The size of your boot partition is rather small. You should be aware that if you don't get rid of old kernels on a regular basis, system updates will likely begin failing to install when your boot partition is completely full. I wouldn't recommend trying to increase the size of your boot partition or moving it to another device unless you know what you're doing (or grab a system image first). I don't know what version of Ubuntu you're running, but more recent versions (last year or two?) remove old kernels when you run `sudo apt-get autoremove`.